# salt + hash session_id Swift & Python

Tags: python, ios, swift, hash

How can I make my security hash more secure for logins on iOS?

My back end is written in Python, and this is currently how I am generating the session_id:

```
u.session_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

When I receive this on the iOS front end I want to add salt and rehash this session id, but I also want to do the same on the back end.

So I would generate session id like this in python:

```
uuid.uuid4().hex
```

and send that down to the front end then I would add salt and rehash and save it

Then, when sending up the session id from the front end, I would use the same also to salt and rehash.

What is a good algorithm I can do in iOS and python in order to salt and rehash? Is there any other ways to make this more secure?

Answer (score 0):

For hashing you can use [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) and for a salt you can use `NSUUID().UUIDString`.